# CSS HTML: Creating A Page With Horizontal Tabs

Tags: html, css, tabs

I am trying to write a web page that displays horizontal tabs across the top.  I have copied the CSS and HTML from several different examples but I always end up with a vertical unordered list of options.  I don't have any other CSS concerning unordered lists that would conflict with what I am experimenting with.  Here is the CSS:

```
#ts_tabmenu {
    font-size: .75em;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
}
#ts_tabmenu ul
{
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
}
#ts_tabmenu ul li
{
    float: left;
}
#ts_tabmenu ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    background: url(tabs.gif) no-repeat left top;
    margin-left: -5px;
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
    color: #666666;
}
#ts_tabmenu ul li a strong
{
    font-weight: normal; /* remove the bold effect */
    display: block;
    background: url(tabs.gif) no-repeat right top;
    padding: 6px 10px 7px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#ts_tabmenu ul li a:hover
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
    background: url(tabs.gif) no-repeat left bottom;
    color: #000000;
}
#ts_tabmenu ul li a:hover strong
{
    background-image: url(tabs.gif) no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
    background-position: right bottom;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div id="ts_tabmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href=#Dashboard><strong>Tutorialsphere</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href=#><strong>Photoshop</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href=#><strong>Illustrator</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href=#><strong>Fireworks</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href=#><strong>Flash</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href=#><strong>CSS</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href=#><strong>PHP</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Did you try to see what was going on with Firebug or an equivalent tool? Hint: add `li { outline: 1px dotted red; }` to see the space occupied by list items.

Answer (score 2):

```
#ts_tabmenu ul li
{
  display:inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

that should do it for you.. the problem with float left is that, if its a block, it takes up the width of the space that it is in.

inline-block will make it only as wide as its contents, you might want to add some paddings/margins according to your style.

Comment: @Kevin, spread some community <3 http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png :)

Comment: Unless you're using IE6 or IE7, you don't need _any_ of the `float: left` rules; `display: inline-block` on the `li` and either `block` or `inline-block` on the `a` tags should be fine. Floating things just adds to the soup.

Comment: i would say that its likely that he is...`You guys appear to be correct. The various codes seem to work fine in IE but always render as a vertical unordered list in Firefox. – Kevin Jun 29 at 19:53`

Answer (score 0):

Works perfect for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/EPSr6/

I added `display: inline-block` to #ts_tabmenu ul li and still worked fine.

Comment: You guys appear to be correct.  The various codes seem to work fine in IE but always render as a vertical unordered list in Firefox.

Comment: @Kevin will you mark my answer as correct if it helped you, please!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working for me in http://jsfiddle.net/7GUVU/

Tab links along the top.

Comment: as said already, its a browser thing, hes testing in old versions of ie.